# Pagination in kundera-cassandra

Tags: java, pagination, cassandra, kundera

I am using kundera-cassandra (V3.2) and want to limit a select query. This is working with following code:

```
TypedQuery<T> query = manager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
query.setMaxResults(limit);
```

My problem is to set a start parameter. I found the method

```
query.setFirstResult(start);
```

but it does not work. Is there any solution available to tell the select query from where to start? I cannot do that on application level because the query is used by a REST service method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `limit, offset` queries and they are not supported by `Kundera-Cassandra` as there is no support on Cassandra natively.

Answer (score 1):

Kundera supports Cassandra Pagination via the Datastax Driver.

The following is an excerpt from the [Kundera readmes](https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/wiki/Datastax-java-driver-support-for-Cassandra-using-Kundera):

**Pagination :** You can paginate the query results fetched from Cassandra using Datastax driver via ResultIterator :

```
String queryString= "Select t from Token t";
com.impetus.kundera.query.Query query = (com.impetus.kundera.query.Query) em.createQuery(queryString,
                Token.class);
query.setFetchSize(fetchSize);
int count=0;
Iterator<Token> tokens = query.iterate();
while(tokens.hasNext())
{
  ...
}
```